# Authenticating my APIs with Laravel Passport / Phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I've just authenticated my APIs based on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

Thing is now, my functional testing with phpunit is broken. I get "Unauthenticated" error.

I tried to use a middleware, a recommended [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/l5-phpunit-testing-the-post-request-with-csrf), but it didn't work.

I guess I would need to include csrf fiels in request, but I don't really know how to do that for testing

Here is my test :

```
$this->json('POST', '/api/v1/category/create',$data)
        ->seeJson($data)
        ->seeInDatabase('category', $data);
```

Any idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware` trait you can use, which'll bypass the authentication middleware (but all the other middleware, too).

The more resilient approach, though, is using [the built-in testing handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#sessions-and-authentication) for authentication. Passing the `actingAs` function a valid user will execute your test as if that user was logged in.

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

$this->actingAs($user)->visit('/');
```

Comment: I'm testing APIs, so I can't use $this->actingAs. As you say, WithoutMiddleware  is ok, but what if I need a Middleware to work??? Updated my question with my test

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro If you read the link I included, it *specifically* states you can use it with APIs. "You may also specify which guard should be used to authenticate the given user by passing the guard name as the second argument to the actingAs method: `$this->actingAs($user, 'api')`"

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly include it in answer, as this was my solution!